# How to make react router protected?

Tags: reactjs

I am just switching from angular to react, i am creating a dynamic routes, but the problem is i don't know how to make it private below is my code.

Please help me to solve this.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    children: Dashboard,
    exact: true,
    authGuard: true,
  },
];

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            children={<route.children />}
          />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        sessionStorage.getItem("token") ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: location } }} />
        )
      }
    ></Route>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering the `Route` component while mapping you can render the PrivateRoute which contains your logic

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          <PrivateRoute
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            children={<route.children />}
          />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Since you specify `authGurad` as an attribute in json, you can use that to choose which Route to render.

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, index) => {
        const Component = route.authGuard? PrivateRoute: Route;
        return (
          <Component
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            children={<route.children />}
          />
        )})}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: But if some routes are not private than what can i do?

Comment: You mean you need some to be private and some to be normal?